# How to show YouTube like ripple effect in android?

Tags: android, rippledrawable, ripple-effect

Latest versions of YouTube app on android shows a ripple which is pretty different.

**That is when we lift our finger from button, then at the time of ending ripple it shows stroke.**

How to achieve this type of ripple in android?

[image: When we lift finger, there is stroke at the end of ripple.]

Comment: I noticed that too. Tried finding a simple way to achieve the same effect but it seems there isn't one

Answer (score 0):

It is actually just a ripple background by setting `android:background="?selectableItemBackground"`

In Youtube button example,

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_chat_search"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground"  <-- ripple effect
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ic_download"

    />

    <TextView
        android:text="Download"
      />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Youtube button shows stroke as a border when we lift our finger.

Comment: You can just set our button `ImageView` as selectable drawable?

Answer (score 0):

Add below two attribute in your click view.

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: Youtube button shows stroke as a border when we lift our finger. This does not shows stroke.